# Radius of largest sphere about a point in a convex hull

Tags: geometry, optimization, convex-analysis, analytic-geometry, convex-optimization

Let $C$ be a convex hull defined such that $C = \{Z \in \mathbb{R}^m | \alpha \le \sum_{k=1}^m Z_k \cdot \phi_k(x) \le \beta\}$ where $\phi_k$ are smooth functions, $x \in [0,1]$, and the $Z_k$'s are the components of $Z$. In practice, the $\phi_k$'s are discretized over $[0,1]$ which implies that numerically $C$ can be described by $n$ constraints where $n$ is the number of mesh points over $[0,1]$.

Let $\tilde{Z} \in C$ be an interior point of this convex hull. I am interested in finding the maximum radius such that a ball centered at $\tilde{Z}$ lies in $C$.

I know that I can easily formulate this as a convex optimization problem using cvx but I am wondering if there are analytical approaches for this problem. The only issue is that $m$ is let's say 200 and while I know cvx can handle high dimensions, having an analytical approach would make it simpler/faster.

I don't really have much background on convex analysis so suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should include a "for all $x\in[0,1]$" inside the definition of your set $C$. Anyway, the radius of the largest sphere centered at $\tilde Z$ is equal to the shortest distance from $\tilde Z$ to any of the $2n$ boundary planes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Rahul. Just to clarify: Suppose that $m=2, n =2$, then if I can write $C$ as $\alpha \le \phi_{11} Z_1 + \phi_{12}Z_2 \le \beta$ and $ \alpha \le \phi_{21} Z_1 + \phi_{22}Z_2 \le \beta$ then $\phi_{11} Z_1 + \phi_{12}Z_2$ and $\phi_{21} Z_1 + \phi_{22}Z_2$ are my boundary planes right?

Comment: Those are just $n$ linear functions. The $2n$ planes are $\phi_{11}Z_1+\phi_{12}Z_2 = \alpha$, $\phi_{11}Z_1+\phi_{12}Z_2 = \beta$, $\phi_{21}Z_1+\phi_{22}Z_2 = \alpha$, and $\phi_{21}Z_1+\phi_{22}Z_2 = \beta$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!